# Scan multiple integers without knowing the actual number of integers

Tags: c, scanf

I have to input values whose frequency i don't know...

For example  first input: 1 32 54 65 6

second input: 2 4 5

What i first thought was, scan the values, if new line '\n' then break the loop, but that didn't go so well, so instead i said i use characters, then i typecast to get the number but the problem with this also came that it scan one character by one and if its its a negative value its also a problem;

Something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int myarray[20];
int i=0, data;

while(1){
      scanf("%d", &data);
      if (data == '\n') break; 
      myarray[i]=data;
}

return 0;
}
```

but then, scanf jumps all the special characters and look for only ints... is there a way to scan ints to an array and when there is a newline it stops?

Comment: and where exactly is `data` defined?

Comment: You can read a whole line, split it on e.g. whitespace, and then convert each part to integers.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read the line and followed by it use `sscanf()`

Comment: For readability I strongly recommend to put `break;` into a new line. Though this may be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice, go for `fgets()`.

1. Read the whole `line` from the input
2. Tokenize using space [] [or your preferred delimiter] [using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)]
3. Allocate memory to store the integer
4. Convert the string input to integer [maybe [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)] and store each integer.

Optionally, you may want to add some validation and error checking.

Read more about `fgets()` [here](http://inux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

<sup>also, don't forget to get rid of the trailing `\n` stored in the read buffer by `fgets()`</sup>

Comment: I see fgets get a string, if i change the data into string using say strtol or atoi am not quite sure if its going to recognize negative values??

Comment: @user3564573 if you notice, the return type is `long int` for `strtol()` and I see no reason not to hadle negative numbers. as for delimiter, you cannot use `-` sign as a delimiter.

Comment: @user3564573 Read the manual page for `strtol()` if you're not familiar with it. Hint: it handles negative values just fine.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out

Comment: Note that `strtok_r` is not a standard function in C, but a common extension in many compilers.

Comment: A limitation with this approach is that the maximum line length needs to be known ahead of time (unless code uses `fgets()` multiple times on the same line - somewhat complicated) and OP implies an unknown count of numbers per line.  IMO such a limitation is not bad, but code should report when a line is read that is longer than expected.

Comment: @chux Thank you sir for mentioning the `extension` regarding `strtok_r()`. Also, by mentioning `some validation and error checking`,  I implied the read buffer length overrun, nevertheless, thanks for elaboration.

Comment: The link to the documentation should be as follows -> https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: @Jean-VictorCôté emmm...did you miss `Read more about fgets() here.` part?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using `fgets()` as suggested by [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27147477/2410359)

Otherwise code can search for `'\n'` before reading each `int`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N (20)

int main(void) {

  int myarray[N];
  int i = 0;

  while (1) {
    int ch;
    while (isspace(ch = fgetc(stdin)) && ch != '\n')
      ;
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
      break;
    ungetc(ch, stdin);

    int data;
    if (scanf("%d", &data) != 1)
      break; // Bad data
    if (i < N)
      myarray[i++] = data;
  }

  return 0;
}
```