# how to assign spaced input numbers in array of unkown length

Tags: c

Currently, I am asking user to specify number of input values being specified.
This the code for it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("\nHow many record you will enter: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    float x[n];
    printf("\n\nEnter the values of velocity (m/s):");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&x[i]);
        printf("\n%f",x[i]);
    }   
}
```

The code runs fine. But, I want to write code in such a way that it will calculate 'n' by scanning the input (numbers separated by space, not necessary one space between each number) without asking the user.
Can you suggest me a way for it.

PS: I am new to coding

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggestion: prefer `int main(void)` over `void main()`.

Comment: Why are you printing a newline *before* the text you want to print? I've seen this more and more among beginners, and it doesn't really make any sense to me. Mostly because output to `stdout` (which is what `printf` writes to) is by default *line buffered*, which means the output is flushed (i.e. actually printed) on newline. So if you print two lines with newline at the beginning then only the first line would be displayed initially.

Comment: I can do what you wanted using string, but taking input as int? Is it possible? i think, not... :(

Comment: As for your problem, if you don't care about *storing* the values then just read in an infinite loop until `scanf` returns `EOF` or `0`. Otherwise you might want to find a tutorial on *pointers* and the [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) functions.

Comment: Or you simply look up all the other "related" questions. This question was asked many times before.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation using `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` is what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233450/in-c-parsing-a-string-of-multiple-whitespace-separated-integers/28233856#28233856

Comment: Can somebody explain it with example. I am struggling to put EOF as condition to while loop

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). Combining both of them , you can design as per your target. Also, you may need to know and use [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) to make use of dynamic memory allocation.

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27147477/2173917) can help you.

Comment: I am trying to use scanf function to find the end of the input as below:                                                                            #include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
 int i,n;
 float x[10];
 printf("\n\nEnter the values of velocity (m/s):");
 while(scanf("%f",&x[i])==1)
 {
  scanf("%f",&x[i]);
  i++;
  n++;
 }
 for (i=0; i>n; i++)
 {
  printf("\n%f",x[i]);
 } 
}                                                                                                                 The while loop is not ending!

Comment: I saw that already and didn't get it. I understood all the steps explained and studied all the functions mentioned there. But I am not sure how to use it for my problem.